# Createjs using inject correctly

Tags: javascript, createjs

So i am starting to use createjs and after drawing some cubes i wanted to change the cubes color which led me to a suprise since this isnt as easy as i though it would be compared to raphaeljs where its just

```
object.attr ("stroke", "#0000FF");
```

Or something similiar, now in createjs there are two ways to change the color of a object the first is to completly redraw the shape setting every single atribute again, which is horrible in my opinion since i would need to save the x,y,width, height and probably other things with diffrent shapes to some data structure. The other way is using something called inject and from the examples that i have seen it goes something like this ([link](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs/10834-animate-shape-colors-for-a-set-timeframe))

```
var shape = new createjs.Shape().set({x:50,y:50});
var g = shape.graphics;

var fillCommand = g.beginFill("#ff0000").command;
// Note that this is equivalent to:
g.beginFill("#ff0000");
var fillCommand = g.command; // The last command

var shapeCommand = g.drawRect(0,0,100,100).command;

// Then later:
fillCommand.style = "#0000ff";
shapeCommand.w = 200;
```

Why it does solve the problem of only needing to change the thing that i want to change it also is very convoluted and i cant find any documentation on what the actual variables (**.style**, **.w** in this case) are for some of those inject commands. So anybody got experience with using this inject style?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Graphics methods in the documentation (such as Graphics.Fill http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Graphics.Fill.html). We definitely want to expand on the documentation, but it should at least give you an idea as to what the API expects.

I don't think it is too complicated, just keep in mind it is a general drawing API, and there is no concept of concrete shape objects with a single stroke or fill. This makes it much more powerful, and you can do way more than just defining a colored polygon.

The example you included is overly illustrated. To create a simple rectangle with a custom stroke, you can do this:

```
var stroke = shape.graphics.beginStroke("#000").command; // Save this to modify it later
shape.graphics.beginFill("#f00").drawRect(0,0,100,100);
stage.addChild(shape);

//Then
stroke.style = "#00f";
```

Here is a quick example:
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/L2tm9xdm/

Or you can do something more complex:
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/L2tm9xdm/1/